# Nginx redirects not getting used

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I have an nginx.conf file that looks something like this:

```
http {

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name myapp.org;
      return 301 http://www.myapp.org$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.myapp.org;
      passenger_enabled on;
      root /var/www/myapp/current/public;
  }

}
```

This seems like the format recommended on this site and others, yet when I go to myapp.org, I just get this message from nginx:

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

Though if I go to www.myapp.org, then everything works as expected. Why aren't the redirects being picked up?

UPDATE:

nginx.conf :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        # passenger_friendly_error_pages on;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##

        passenger_root /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.4;
        passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  coolthearth.net;
        return 301 http://www.cooltheearth.org$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.coolthearth.net;
        return 301 http://www.cooltheearth.org$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  coolthearth.org;
        return 301  http://www.cooltheearth.org$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.cooltheearth.org;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /var/www/rails_backend/current/public;
    }

}


# mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# }
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you test it / what's the real domain ?

Comment: The real domain is [here](http://www.cooltheearth.org).

Comment: Did you reload nginx ? What's the complete configuration ?

Comment: Yep, I've reloaded. Just added the full config

Comment: Ok nothing bad on this part. What's in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` ?

Comment: There's nothing in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, and sites-enabled only has the default. I posted the contents of default above, though I don't believe I'm loading it in the nginx.conf.

Comment: It's included as you have `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf` in your nginx.conf file. Although that's not the reason for this behaviour, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typos in your `server_name` directives.

You wrote `coolthearth` instead of `cooltheearth` in 3 places.

Testing the current setup with a typo gives :

```
curl -H "Host: coolthearth.org" "http://104.131.135.243" -I
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:22:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.cooltheearth.org/
```

Fix these and it will work.